# How to check constraints before creating an object using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I write my own unit converter. I have Measure.class, which have fields `BigDecimal value` and `Unit unit` (Unit.class is my own abstract class with many implementations, which means e.g. meter, inches, kelvin etc)

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class Measure {
    BigDecimal value;
    Unit unit;

    public Measure(BigDecimal value, Unit unit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

Also I've created abstract MeasureConstraint.class with `check()` method and a lot of it's implemetations (like TemperatureConstraint.class). `check()` method should be called when object Measure created.

What do I want to get, for example:

```
Measure measure = new Measure (5, *Kelvin*); // OK
Measure measure = new Measure (-5, *Kelvin*); // exception, Kelvin should be 0 or greater
```

I've tried to insert field `List<MeasureConstraint> constraints` to the Measure.class (and add this field to constructor parameters for @Autowired), filter by type this list to get needed constraint and call it's `check()` method in constructor.

But this solution makes it impossible for me to simple create Measure objects by myself (not using Spring) at the other classes in my application, because now I must create by myself `List<MeasureConstraint> constraints` too (I understand that Spring does not work in this situation). The reason I need to create Measure object by myself is because I need to create temporary variable during the conversion process.

I just started learning Spring and do not completely understand conceptions of IoC and DI. Maybe I shouldn't use manual object creation ever and nowhere if I'm using Spring? Should I inject all temporary variables as fields of my Converter.class and use them in `convert() method thus avoiding manual object creation? Please give me some advices.

*Sory for my /Google translate/ English =)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a separate class which would be responsible for creating `Measure` objects. There you could inject your `MeasureConstraint` beans and perform the logic of validating data before creating measures.

Something like that:

```
@Component
public class MeasureFactory {
    @Autowired // actually it's better to inject via constructor
    private List<MeasureConstraint> constraints;
    

    public Measure createMeasure(BigDecimal value, Unit unit) {
        // perform validation using constraints
        return new Measure(value, unit);
    }
}
```

Comment: and so I understand how to use the "Factory" pattern =) thank you, Igor!